# cc1plus.exe: fatal error: world.cpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

i have problem with the code
everytime the code is done, running the code is still normal. when exiting visual code studio and re-entering, the code does not run end show the error as below

cc1plus.exe: fatal error: world.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: Believe your compiler when it tells you that "world.cpp" is not in the directory that the compiler is looking.

Comment: Maybe you have a space in the path. Maybe you have a bug in your tasks.json if you are using that. Maybe you are using some other extension but did not mention. I am doubtful that anyone can help.

Comment: My crystal ball says that your file is called "hello world.cpp", and that you are not surrounding the name with quotes when compiling. But it's not entirely clear what "re-entering" is, so it might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error, and to fix the error is easy. It may because your file name contains spaces. More information about this and how I know this is here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5QxAjaiQp8. (Altough he got the different error raised but the way to fix it is still the same).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by removing the spaces between the name of the file I was saving. Earlier I was naming my c++ file as example- "test file.cpp", but when I removed the blank space i.e. "testfile.cpp" or "test_file.cpp", the error resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling the code using your terminal, you could check if the file you want to run is in that folder using `dir` for Windows or `ls` for Linux. If it is not, change to the folder where the file is and try running the file again.